# Difference between 'gear up' and 'ready'

Tags: differences, idioms

> Software programmers are **gearing up** to build applications for the newest version of Windows Phone 7.

It seems the 'gear up' in here means 'ready'. So why not use 'ready' and  what's the difference with 'ready'?

Comment: you're talking about `ready` as verb here right?

Comment: Of note, "ready up" is a common enough phrase that it deserves some mention. It does not work in this context as "... they are readying up to build ..." sounds forced. "Ready up" more or less means "Let's go" or "Gear up."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *gear up* is synonymous with *ready*. But then, *ready* is also synonymous with *prepare*… “Gear up” has some implications that you will be readying your equipment (your gear), though it can also be used figuratively.

All in all, I don't see a big difference between these uses of *gear up*, *ready* and *prepare*.

Comment: I find "gear up" in this sense to have a very journalistic flavour. Looking on the British National Corpus, it has 24 hits for "gear up", 16 of them  actually containing this phrase (as opposed to eg "put his gear up on top"). 2 are in the literal sense of "put your gear on", 9 - 11 of them are from newspapers and magazines, and 2 from business meetings. 1 - 3 are from books.

Comment: @Colin: I do agree that *gear up* is more colloquial, and thus used mostly in spoken English or in journalistic style.

Comment: you mean 'figuratively'. Do the 'gear up' make you imagine the  gears? If so, then, It's really figuratively.

Comment: While I agree that _gear up_ and _ready_ are synonyms, it is important to note that _gearing up_ and _ready_ are not. _Ready_ would not work in the OP's example sentence, as it would indicate that the software programmers are presently building applications rather than just preparing to. Preserving the gerund with _readying_ would indicate that the subject is still in the process of preparing.

Answer (score 6):

*[Gearing up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gearing+up)* means ***getting*** ready:

> To get ready for a coming action or event

Comment: what's the diff: "getting ready" and "ready" ? "getting ready" means the process and 'ready' means the status ?

Answer (score 1):

Readying is to be used in place of 'gearing up' as per your question, and the sentence will be

> Software programmers are readying to
> build applications for the newest
> version of Windows Phone 7.

I don't find it alright and with a little help from OED, I'd like to explain.

From OED:

> verb (readies, readying, readied)
>
> [with object]    prepare for an action or purpose:
>
> the spare transformer was readied for shipment
>
> [with object and infinitive] :
>
> she readied herself to speak first

So, as I see it, the word ready can be used as a verb only in the above two cases and in the sentence you quoted, ready can replace *gearing up* if it takes *'themselves'* as object. Then the sentence will be,

> Software programmers are readying themselves to build applications for the newest version of Windows Phone 7.

But, I think usage of *gearing up* here will be more positive and beautiful. Choice of words plays a very important role in conveying the meaning to the readers as well as capturing their minds. *Gearing up* is an apt choice here.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers :) Gear up and ready are not always synonymous.

Comment: I agree but I don't think it's totally clear.  The problem in the first sentence is that it should be *readying themselves*, otherwise there is no object.  The verb *gear up* on the other hand, does not require an object.

Comment: @z7sg - Thanks for the correction, edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I perceive "gear up" to also imply a certain level of excitement, so that the programmers are also excited about the project.  Compare the sentence

> Software programmers are gearing up to build applications for the newest version of Windows Phone 7.

with

> Software programmers are preparing to build applications for the newest version of Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

Using "ready" as an intransitive verb sounds awkward to me:

> programmers are readying *themselves* to...

sounds ok, but

> programmers are readying to...

does not. In addition, "gearing up" is computer lingo, along with "spooling up", "spinning up", "firing up", ...

Comment: "gearing up" sounds more like it comes from the military rather than software.

Comment: I am willing to bet you are right about that, Mitch...though I would not care to speculate on "firing up".

Comment: "firing up" sounds like a coal driven engine being prepared.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are *not* synonymous. If programmers are *gearing up* to do this, it means they are actively working on preparations. If they're *ready*, they may simply be sitting around waiting for a beta release of WP7. Being ready is not the same as making ready.

Comment: “ready” is also a verb, in which case the question makes much more sense.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. *Ready* can (rarely) be a verb, but even then it would normally need an object. *Programmers are readying themselves* is just about ok, though most people would say *...getting ready*. But it's often important to distinguish working on *becoming* ready from actually *being* ready *already* (Yiddishism unintended)